# How to delay the search in list.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listjs

I'm using **[list.js](https://listjs.com/)** for filtering and searching, my list is very large and I need to delay the search for it, but the documentation doesn't show any examples of how to do so, all it says is this: https://listjs.com/api/#searchDelay

One example of how to do so would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the table example from [List.js](https://listjs.com/examples/table/) which I have used in this snippet to demonstrate the usage of `searchDelay`. Below snippet code sets a delay of 1 second before starting a search on the list. As per the [changelog](https://github.com/javve/list.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), this feature has been included with version `2.3.0`

```js
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ],
  searchDelay: 1000 // 1 second
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
```

```css
.list {
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
td {
  padding:10px; 
  border:solid 1px #eee;
}

input {
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding:7px 14px;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
input:focus {
  outline:none;
  border-color:#aaa;
}
.sort {
  padding:8px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #28a8e0;
  height:30px;
}
.sort:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color:#1b8aba;
}
.sort:focus {
  outline:none;
}
.sort:after {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  content:"";
  position: relative;
  top:-10px;
  right:-5px;
}
.sort.asc:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  content:"";
  position: relative;
  top:4px;
  right:-5px;
}
.sort.desc:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
  content:"";
  position: relative;
  top:-4px;
  right:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort by name
  </button>
  <table>
    <!-- IMPORTANT, class="list" have to be at tbody -->
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonny Stromberg</td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonas Arnklint</td>
        <td class="born">1985</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Martina Elm</td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</td>
        <td class="born">1983</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/2.3.1/list.min.js"></script>
```